# Right align a view RelativeToView in a RelativeLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to align a view in the top right corner of another view in Xamarin.Forms. I believe this has to be possible with a `RelativeLayout`, but I have not figured out how to do it the right way (in XAML at best).

I have a solution that works for me for one Device, but I'm afraid that this won't port between Idioms/Platforms/Devices. Im my XAML I have defined my image in XAML

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="RelativeLayout">
    <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1/" 
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.5, Constant=0}" 
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=.5, Constant=0}" 
           x:Name="Image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In code behind I am creating the badge to add to the image

```
Badge badge = new Badge()
{
  Count = 4
}
RelativeLayout.Children.Add(badge, 
    Constraint.RelativeToView(Image, (l, v) => v.X + v.Width - 22), 
    Constraint.RelativeToView(Image, (l, v) => v.Y));
```

(please do not ask me, where the 22 comes from, this is simple magic at this point, but necessary, since the badge is not layouted, yet and hence has a width of 0). It - kind of - works (see image). But - as stated before - I doubt that this will work on other Idions/Systems.

[image: Badge image]

I would have believed that something like

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="RelativeLayout">
    <Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1/" 
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.5, Constant=0}" 
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=.5, Constant=0}" 
           x:Name="Image"/>
    <views:Badge Count="4" x:Name="Badge"
                 RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=Image, Property=Right}"
                 RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=Image, Property=Y}" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

would work, but there is no `Right` property and setting the `XConstraint` to `Property=Width, Scale=1.0` does not work either, since the badge will be placed `Image.Width` on the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Wrap the Small Image in a StackLayout which fills your RelativeLayout and Align it to the Right.
Something like that:

```
<AbsoluteLayout Padding="50">
    <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <ContentView BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

like an example, Iam placing the view below a searchbar with constraints 0,0
c#

```
 this._baseLayout.Children.Add(
                mapView,
                Constraint.RelativeToView(autoComplete, (r, v) => v.X),
                Constraint.RelativeToView(autoComplete, (r, v) => autoComplete.HeightOfSearchBar),
                heightConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((r) => r.Height - autoComplete.HeightOfSearchBar),
                widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(autoComplete, (r, v) => v.Width));
xaml
```

Comment: <RelativeLayout x:Name="_baseLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

Comment: Yeah, but this does not work until everything is layouted, right?